# Handle similar location with different blocks

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I have a react app that I would like to show for a specific path. A similar path is used for the backend, though. This is a legacy app and other static files are shown using a different endpoint.

I'm not able to show the content appropriately. I'm either showing the old files, or I'm corrupting the similar path, or NGINX is appending infinity /index.html at the end of the path.

If it sounds confusing what I wrote, maybe the illustration below will help:

```
location / -> leave uwsgi to handle the requests
location /static/ -> serve static folder
location /request/ -> serve new react app
location /request_auth/ -> serve new react app
location /request_auth/token... -> leave uwsgi to handle the requests
```

This is what I have at the moment and it is not working!

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  myapp.com;

    root /var/www/myapp/static/;

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass unix:///var/www/myapp/uwsgi/uwsgi.sock;
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_param HTTPS on;
    }

    # I think I can remove this block...
    location ^~ /static/ {
        alias /var/www/myapp/static/;
    }

    location ^~ /request/ {
        alias /var/www/myapp/reactstatic/;
    }

    # from down here it is not working properly. I've tried using
    # location =/request_auth/
    # location /request_auth/ 
    # and other variations in the other block as well. All unsuccessful 
    location ^~ /request_auth/ {
        alias /var/www/myapp/reactstatic/;
    }

    location ~^/request_auth/[a-zA-Z0-9]+ {
        uwsgi_pass unix:///var/www/myapp/uwsgi/uwsgi.sock;
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_param HTTPS on;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was getting weird redirects. Also, my react app had a static folder and the second uwsgi was trying to handle that.

This is what I did and it's working, but I'm sure there is a better solution.

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  myapp.com;

    root /var/www/myapp/static/;

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass unix:///var/www/myapp/uwsgi/uwsgi.sock;
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_param HTTPS on;
    }

    # I think I can remove this block...
    location ^~ /static/ {
        alias /var/www/myapp/static/;
    }

    location ^~ /request/ {
        alias /var/www/myapp/reactstatic/;
    }
    location ^~ /request/ {
        alias /var/www/myapp/reactstatic/static;
    }

    location ^~ /request_auth/ {
        alias /var/www/myapp/reactstatic/;
    }
    location ^~ /request_auth/ {
        alias /var/www/myapp/reactstatic/static;
    }

    location ~^/request_auth/[a-zA-Z0-9]+ {
        uwsgi_pass unix:///var/www/myapp/uwsgi/uwsgi.sock;
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_param HTTPS on;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```